# 「yum update エラー」時に表示される「パッケージ」「要求」「削除中」「次のものにより更新された」の意味は、それぞれ何ですか？

Tags: centos, yum

「yum update エラー」時に「パッケージ」「要求」「削除中」「次のものにより更新された」と表示されるのですが、それぞれどういう意味ですか？
・「uwsgi-plugin-python36u-2.0.17.1-1.ius.el7.x86_64 (ius)」パッケージでエラーが発生？
・「python36u」をリクエストしたのに、「python36u-3.6.4-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (@ius)」があったので(実行が最後まで行われたら)削除します？
・ 最終的に「python3-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64 (updates)」となればよい？　ということは「yum install python3-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64」と打てばよい？

```
   $ sudo yum update

-//中略

--> 依存性解決を終了しました。
エラー: パッケージ: uwsgi-plugin-python36u-2.0.17.1-1.ius.el7.x86_64 (ius)
             要求: uwsgi-plugin-common = 2.0.17.1
            削除中: uwsgi-plugin-common-2.0.16-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
                uwsgi-plugin-common = 2.0.16-1.el7
            次のものにより更新された: : uwsgi-plugin-common-2.0.18-8.el7.x86_64 (epel)
                uwsgi-plugin-common = 2.0.18-8.el7
エラー: パッケージ: uwsgi-plugin-python36u-2.0.17.1-1.ius.el7.x86_64 (ius)
             要求: python36u
            削除中: python36u-3.6.4-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 (@ius)
                python36u = 3.6.4-1.ius.centos7
            次のものにより不要にされた: : python3-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64 (updates)
                見つかりません
 問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができます。
 これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

環境
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

---

下記を実行したら、pythonが表示されたので、pythonがおかしいと思うのですが、

```
$ sudo rpm -Va --nodigest
//中略
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py が見つかりません。
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/baseparser.py が見つかりません。
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/cmdoptions.py が見つかりません。
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands が見つかりません。
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py が見つかりません。
  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/__pycache__ が見つかりません。
//中略
```

現状、Python 2.7.5 と Python 3.6.4 があります。

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.4

$ which python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

パッケージの更新にあたって依存関係を解決しようとしたけど、コンフリクトが起きて解決できない状態になっています。

コンフリクトが起きた際、「パッケージが修正されるのを待つ」だけの場合もありますが、今回は以下の点が問題だと思われます。

- updates, epel, ius と複数のリポジトリを参照している
- CentOS の更新が放置されている

updates は CentOS 公式のリポジトリですが、epel, ius, remi などサードパーティーのリポジトリを利用する際は注意が必要です。
常に有効にしておくのではなく、必要時のみリポジトリを有効にした方が安全です。

恐らくPython 3.6.4 は ius からインストールしたもの (`python36u-3.6.4-1.ius.centos7.x86_64`) のようですが、updates にも `python3-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64` が配布されているのでコンフリクトが起きています。

あなたが管理している CentOS 7.2 の運用ポリシー次第ですが、「CentOS 7.9 に更新する」「IUS 経由で入れた Python 3 はいったん削除し、CentOS オフィシャルな Python 3 を入れ直す」が分かりやすいと思います。

**参考:**

- [python36u update replacement conflict with python 3.6 EPEL #11](https://github.com/iusrepo/python36/issues/11)
- [Python 3 plan #7](https://github.com/iusrepo/packaging/issues/7#issuecomment-545038676)

Comment: Python 3 をいったん削除後、再度「yum update」を実行したら、無事「完了しました!」と表示されました。